# SQL Server Pivot query taking too long

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble on executing this query

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
   (SELECT 
        A.ItemNo, A.EquipmentID, A.AssetAccountCode, A.Descrip,
        B.Condition, B.[Year], 
        C.Brand, C.Model, C.TechnicalSpecs,
        D.[Type], D.Criticallity, D.[Status],
        (CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), d.YearInstalled, 127)) AS Yearinstalled 
    FROM  
        tbl_Masterlist A 
    JOIN  
        tbl_Condition B ON A.EquipmentID = B.EquipmentID 
    JOIN  
        tbl_TechnicalSpecification C ON b.EquipmentID = c.EquipmentID    
    JOIN 
       tbl_Status D On c.EquipmentID = d.EquipmentID) src 
PIVOT 
    (MAX(CONDITION) FOR YEAR IN ([2014], [2015], [2016])) piv
```

The problem is that the output wont show or the executing time is too long (I've tried to wait for 30 minutes and its still executing).

Any ideas why is this happening? and what should I do.

I'm guessing the cause of this is because of the records of the 4 tables. each tables have 16000 records, and some of their IDs are blank.

Comment: Does it help if you add where to `FROM  tbl_Masterlist A where year in (2014,2015,2016) `

Comment: The year column should be divided in three columns.

Comment: What I mean is if you are only using 2014, 2015 and 2016 for the pivot columns but if your date range in the table is from 1960 to 2016, if you put the where on the inner select it might speed up the query.